# Redirect with parameter to same url

Tags: nginx

I have a server with nginx and I have to make that whenever they write a domain url it is redirected to the same domain but with a parameter, that is:

http: // my-site => http: // my-site / blue

but when i use rewrite:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-site.org;
    index index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/my-site.com;
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       rewrite ^/ /blue;
    }
}
```

Or use return:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host/blue;
    server_name my-site.org;
    index index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/my-site.com;
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I receive the error 500 internal server error

In front use angular 6

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/335129/94862

Comment: The problem is if I do not work with some redirect the page works well, taking blue as a parameter, but if I do the redirect it takes blue as if it were a folder and nginx sends error 404